# Stable seasonality F-test does not meet assumptions for one way ANOVA

Tags: anova, assumptions, seasonality, f-test

I am having trouble to understand Stable seasonality F-test. I know it is basically the same test as one way ANOVA, but the assumptions for one way ANOVA can´t be met for it. For ANOVA the data should be independent, random, normally distributed and variances of the groups should be same.

And now my problem, which of those assumptions can not be met in the seasonality F-test? Just the random and independent sample? Or the variances as well?

And what does it mean for the seasonality F-test? Is there any problem I have to keep in mind when using the seasonality F-test?

Thank you for answers!